# Increasing size no of mapper

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to PIG and HDFS. Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a lot of flat text LZO compressed ill formatted server logs files - about 2 GB each getting generated from around 400 servers daily.

I am trying to take advantage of map reduce to format and clean up the data in HDFS using my java formatter and then load the output in Hive.

My problem is that my PIG scripts spawns only one mapper which takes around 15 mins. to read the file sequentially. This is not practical for amount of data I have to load daily in hive.

Here is my pig script.

```
SET default_parallel 100;
SET output.compression.enabled true;
SET output.compression.codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
SET mapred.min.split.size 256000;
SET mapred.max.split.size 256000;
SET pig.noSplitCombination true; 
SET mapred.max.jobs.per.node 1;

register file:/apps/pig/pacudf.jar
raw1 = LOAD '/data/serverx/20120710/serverx_20120710.lzo' USING PigStorage() as (field1);
pac = foreach raw1 generate pacudf.filegenerator(field1);
store pac into '/data/bazooka/';
```

Looks like mapred.min.split.size setting isn't working. I can see only 1 mapper being initiated which works on the whole 2 GB file on a single server of the cluster. As we have a 100 node cluster I was wondering if I can make use for more servers in parallel if I can spawn more mappers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression support in PigStorage does not provide [splitting ability](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/11/hadoop-at-twitter-part-1-splittable-lzo-compression/). For splittable lzo compression support with pig, you would need the [elephant-bird library from twitter](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird). Also to get splitting work (properly ?) with existing regular-lzo files, you would need to index them prior to loading in your pig script.